# Making this code more efficient

Tags: automation, applescript

I made some code in AppleScript to save me some time typing things involved in a game. The code is really extremely repetitive and I'm not sure how to make it less repetitive. I'm relatively new to this language and I'm unsure how to do it in Apple script. I thought maybe I could input names in a list or dictionary.

```
tell application "System Events"
delay 3.0 #Comment

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Truthful_Demise"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Truthful_demise"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Medso"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Medso"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Amazed"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Amazed"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Xyrose"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Xyrose"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Banana"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Banana"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Affiliating"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Affiliating"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show ValentinesDay"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen ValentinesDay"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Haef"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Haef"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Cumulative"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Cumulative"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show ChickenSpawner"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen ChickenSpawner"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Curium"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Curium"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show KeyLargo"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen KeyLargo"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show KeyWest"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen KeyWest"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show modso_246"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen modso_246"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Anonymity"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Anonymity"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Absconding"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Absconding"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show HeroArmour"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen HeroArmour"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show MothersDay"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen MothersDay"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show ModsoIsLove"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen ModsoIsLove"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show WinnDixie"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen WinnDixie"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show TheBreakfastClub"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen TheBreakfastClub"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show wolfwolfypower"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen wolfwolfypower"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show BreachedBase"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen BreachedBase"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show ValarieTheWeird"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen ValarieTheWeird"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show WitchSpawner"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen WitchSpawner"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show Akun"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen Akun"
keystroke return

delay 1.5
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/f show ModsoIsLife"
keystroke return
delay 0.1
keystroke "t"
delay 0.1
keystroke "/seen ModsoIsLife"
keystroke return

end tell
```

Comment: Use list with a loop or create a function that you can call with different parameters.I am sure you can find some good solutions after completing any applescript basic tutorial.You can also find plenty of examples if you will look trough applescript questions from here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put the names in the list, and use a loop to iterate through list

```
set myList to {"Truthful_demise", "Medso", "Amazed", "Xyrose", "Banana", "Affiliating", "ValentinesDay", "Haef", "Cumulative", "ChickenSpawner", "Curium", "KeyLargo", "KeyWest", "modso_246", "Anonymity", "Absconding", "HeroArmour", "MothersDay", "ModsoIsLove", "WinnDixie", "TheBreakfastClub", "wolfwolfypower", "BreachedBase", "ValarieTheWeird", "WitchSpawner", "Akun", "ModsoIsLife"}

tell application "System Events"
    delay 3.0 #Comment
    repeat with thisText in myList
        delay 1.5
        keystroke "t"
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "/f show " & thisText & return
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "t"
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "/seen " & thisText & return
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Additional to this you can use Script Objects.